# How to change block confirmations with geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

It appears that geth waits for 5 blocks to confirm a block.  Is there any way to change the number of blocks to wait for confirmation?

Comment: Where do you see the number 5?

Comment: In the geth log: I0208 21:57:10.985738 miner/unconfirmed.go:105]   mined block #5037 [ebe74549…] reached canonical chain
I0208 21:57:10.985765 miner/unconfirmed.go:83]   mined potential block #5042 [a1b97df2…], waiting for 5 blocks to confirm
I0208 21:57:10.986022 miner/worker.go:514] commit new work on block 5043 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 231.449µs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard-coded, so the only way to change it would be to edit the source yourself, and rebuild.

---

In Geth's `miner` package, in `worker.go`, each [`worker`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/7734ead52030a6c128613331ea4a24afd9d4173a/miner/worker.go#L128) is started with the [following values](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/7734ead52030a6c128613331ea4a24afd9d4173a/miner/worker.go#L141). The `5` represents the depth of the chain of unconfirmed blocks that are kept locally.

```
unconfirmed:    newUnconfirmedBlocks(eth.BlockChain(), 5),
```

If any further blocks are mined, the older, still-unconfirmed blocks are [removed](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/b792412d3101456bded148e122d9e8c2a0829ba0/miner/unconfirmed.go#L89) from the local chain.

The value of `5` seems to be arbitrarily set [and](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/b792412d3101456bded148e122d9e8c2a0829ba0/miner/unconfirmed.go#L45)...

> It is used by the miner to provide logs to the user when a previously
> mined block has a high enough guarantee to not be reorganised out of
> the canonical chain.

I don't know what effect changing it would have. Presumably in a live public network it'd be unlikely that more than 5 consecutive blocks would be mined by the same miner.

Comment: Why is it significant for the blocks to be consecutively mined by the same miner? 

Different miners mining block simultaneously at equal intervals can also result in a fork right? If the forked chains grow together continuously at the same pace for, say, 100 blocks - what would happen? Obviously they'd slip by the 5 confirmation check, yes?